# docker-compose permission denied

Tags: php, apache, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am getting a permission denied error when trying to start up my containers using docker-compose.

Error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/sites/api/var/lib/mysql/mysql'
[1503] Failed to execute script docker-compose

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache 
COPY httpd.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/ 
RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf 
RUN a2ensite httpd.conf 
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN mkdir /var/www/sites/api 
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/sites/api
COPY . /var/www/sites/api 
RUN apt-get update && \
   docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \ apt-get clean && \ apt-get install
 -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* RUN printf "\n" 
 | pecl install imagick 
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
     qa_api_test:
      build:
      context: ./
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     db:
      image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxx
     ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: The user running docker-compose must have permissions to perform the mount. Trying running `sudo docker-compose up -d` to see if you can mount the volume.

Comment: This tells me you need to change permissions on the `/var/lib/mysqli directory. What are the permissions on that directory?

Answer (score -4):

Try running `sudo docker-compose up -d`. Mind the `sudo`.